# How can I click on multiple drop down list on a page with Python and Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to click on multiple dropdown lists on a page but I keep getting an error saying that my list object has no attribute tag_name'.

My code

```
def click_follow_buttons(driver):
    selects = Select(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jBa"))#jBa
    print selects
    for select in selects:
        select.select_by_index(0)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("bA").click()
```

My traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_follow.py", line 50, in <module>
    if click_follow_buttons(driver) == False:
  File "google_follow.py", line 18, in click_follow_buttons
    selects = Select(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jBa"))#jBa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py", line 35, in __init__
    if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

The Html dropdown

```
<div class="jBa XG">
<div class="ny dl d-k-l" jslog="7128; track:impression">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using the `find_elements_by_class_name()` method that would return you a *list of web elements* matching a class name and not a single element.

But, even if you would use `find_element_by_class_name()` instead, you'll get a different error since this is a `div` element matching the class name and not a `select` element.

Comment: @alexce I was first =P

Comment: @drets well, there is a difference in the answers though :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass to constructor of `Select` class web element which has `select` tag name: 
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html

> Constructor. A check is made that the given element is, indeed, a
>   SELECT tag. If it is not, then an UnexpectedTagNameException is
>   thrown.